# Using a factory to create QT promoted widgets

Tags: c++, qt

Promoting widgets is one of the best features in the QT Designer. But when using the designer, it 'new's the object there it self ( inside setupUi ). This limits the ability to extend the interface file.

Is it possible to use a factory of some sort to get the promoted widgets, so that when a sub class of a promoted widget is required, this could be achieved via changing the factory and returning the sub class of the widget.

requirement:

```
NamePanel* myPanel;
void setupUi(QWidget* pWidget)
{
     myPanel = Factory::CreateNamePanel();
}
```

Is there a work around to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems not to be possible to add a factory into the Ui files. A workaround would be to have a QWidget with an attached layout in the ui and add the factory generated widget to this layout.

[image]

The code would look like this:

```
ui->setupUi(this);

QWidget *panel = Factory::CreateNamePanel();
ui->namePanelContainer->layout()->addWidget(panel);
```